# Hibernate Entity with more than one self relations (recursive relations)

Tags: database, hibernate, entity-relationship

I have got a Hibernate Entity called `Article`, From a database perspective I want to store the next chapter id and previous chapter id within the same table so there are two one-to-one relations of the table with itself and `nextArticleId` and `previousArticleId` are foreign keys from the same table.

My question is that is there a proposed way to deal with situation when creating a Hibernate entity for this? or I just treat this as two normal one-to-one relations and just have two different `Article` objects within the `Article` entity to represent the next article and previous article?

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question**:

> Is that is there a proposed way to deal with situation when creating a Hibernate entity for this?

**Answer**:

> Treat this as two normal one-to-one relations and just have two different Article objects within the Article

Answer (score 1):

It is a normal way to have such mapping

```
class Article {

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_article_prev")
    private Article previouse;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_article_next")
    private Article next;

}
```

Comment: Thanks v.ladynev, I just wanted to know that there is something special in Hibernate to do that.

Comment: @Tefa I think no. Keep in mind that Hibernate will use the first level cache (`Session`) to not create extra `Article`.